# How to send an email when connection to teradata fails?

Tags: sas

I'm using the standard way of connecting to Teradata from SAS like below:

```
connect to teradata (user="youruserid" password="yourpassword" server="servername" mode=teradata);
```

I have multiple such codes which are scheduled one after the other. What I realized is that if Teradata server is down sometime then few codes fail. I want to do is to get an email each time such connection failure happens in SAS.

Comment: So that's an explicit pass through query?

Comment: When CONNECT TO fails does SAS set SYSCC, SYSRC or some SQL macro variable.  Once you have a flag that reflects success/fail sending e-mail is easy.

Comment: Agree with _null_. If the failed connection alone doesn't set one of those macro cars, I would think failed attempt to read a table would. And even if it didn't, you could test your output sas dataset to see if it existed and had > 0 records.